# RegEx to replace html entities

Tags: javascript, html, regex

all. I'm looking for a way to replace the bullet character in Greasemonkey. I assume a Regular Expression will do the trick, but I'm not as well-versed in it as many of you.

For example, "SampleSite.com • Page Title" becoming "SampleSite.com  Page Title". The issue is that the character has already been parsed by the time Greasemonkey has gotten to it, and I don't know how to make it recognize the symbol.

I've tried these so far, but they haven't worked:

```
newTitle = document.title.replace(/•/g, "");
newTitle = document.title.replace("•", ""); //just for grins, but didn't work anyway
```

Comment: Maybe the symbol is actually encoded in the title, if that's not finding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, if Malvolio's solution isn't working

```
newTitle = document.title.replace(/\&bull\;/g, '');
newTitle = newTitle.replace(/([^a-zA-Z0-9-_\s\/\\\(\)\'\"\&\+\.]+)/g, '');
```

Comment: This is close to what I need, but it doesn't take page titles with periods or apostrophes into account, so I modified it a bit. Thank you for the original RegEx! newTitle = document.title.replace(/([^a-zA-Z0-9-_\s\/\\\(\)\.']+)/g, '');

Answer (score 1):

```
document.title = document.title.replace(/•/g, "");
```

works for me.

Answer (score 1):

HTML entities defined by code between `&` and `;` replace `&amp;#183;` or `&amp;middot;` (probably in your case) based on page encoding. Better encode html before using RegEx to replace.